# Inputbox in [excel] [vba] to select range from a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

When I go through my sub line by line it works, but when i just click run it stops after the input box and gives me"run-time error '1004': Activate method of range class failed" for `Newloc.Select`

```
Dim Original As Workbook
Dim Newloc As Range
Dim Newbk As Workbook
Set Original = ActiveWorkbook
Set Newloc = Application.InputBox("Select workbook and cell where to copy the data", "Paste", , , , , , 8)
Newloc.Select
Set Newbk = ActiveWorkbook
Original.Activate
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Copy
Newbk.Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Original.Close savechanges:=False
```

How can I get this to work with the ribbon shortcut I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't select a range in a workbook that is not yet active. The deeper problem is that [you should not rely on `Activate`/`Select` in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for Excel. :)

Solution is to refactor your code so that you don't *need* to rely on activating sheets back & forth:

```
Dim Original As Workbook
Dim srcRange As Range
Dim Newloc As Range
Dim Newbk As Workbook
Set Original = ActiveWorkbook
Set srcRange = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

Set Newloc = Application.InputBox("Select workbook and cell where to copy the data", "Paste", , , , , , 8)

srcRange.Copy Newloc
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Original.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198619/discussion-on-answer-by-david-zemens-inputbox-in-excel-vba-to-select-range-f).